# Multiqueries recognize matched field

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I've a document containing two search relevant fields: **Name** and **NativeName**.

If the a result is shown because it matches Name it would show the user the content of name, it it matches because of NativeName I would this field to teh user.

When matching both its not important to decide which one is shown.

Thats how i create my query:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("Name", searchTerm));
Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("NativeName", searchTerm));
booleanQuery.Add(query1, Occur.SHOULD);
booleanQuery.Add(query2, Occur.SHOULD);
```

How can I found out wether the document was found because of the "Name" or "NativeName" field?

Comment: You can look into `IndexSearcher.explain` or use a `Highlighter`.

Comment: can you post an example with highlighter? and / or indexsearcher? currently can't figure out this